# railstutorial-- stuck on ch10, listing 10.55

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

So I get this error when I run a test:

```
    FAIL["test_password_reset", UserMailerTest, 0.714736877]
 test_password_reset#UserMailerTest (0.71s)
        Expected: ["noreply@example.com"]
          Actual: ["from@example.com"]
        test/mailers/user_mailer_test.rb:23:in `block in <class:UserMailerTest>'

  39/39: [===================================================] 100% Time: 00:00:03, Time: 00:00:03

Finished in 3.45232s
39 tests, 182 assertions, 1 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

I'm not sure what to fix. Here's my user_mailer_test.rb:

```
require 'test_helper'

class UserMailerTest < ActionMailer::TestCase

  test "account_activation" do
    user = users(:michael)
    user.activation_token = User.new_token
    mail = UserMailer.account_activation(user)
    assert_equal "Account activation", mail.subject
    assert_equal [user.email], mail.to
    assert_equal ["noreply@example.com"], mail.from
    assert_match user.name,               mail.body.encoded
    assert_match user.activation_token,   mail.body.encoded
    assert_match CGI::escape(user.email), mail.body.encoded
  end

  test "password_reset" do
    user = users(:michael)
    user.reset_token = User.new_token
    mail = UserMailer.password_reset(user)
    assert_equal "Password reset", mail.subject
    assert_equal [user.email], mail.to
    assert_equal ["noreply@example.com"], mail.from
    assert_match user.reset_token,        mail.body.encoded
    assert_match CGI::escape(user.email), mail.body.encoded
  end
end
```

and my user_mailer.rb:

```
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer

  def account_activation(user)
    @user = user
    mail to: user.email, from: "noreply@example.com", subject: "Account activation"
  end

  def password_reset(user)
    @user = user
    mail to: user.email, subject: "Password reset"
  end
end
```

Please help. I'm stuck at this and I'm not too sure on what the problem is. Thank you.

Comment: In `password_reset` don't you have to pass `from`

Comment: Look back at 10.10: `class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "noreply@example.com"
  layout 'mailer'
end`

Comment: @ShawnPatrickRice that worked! I can't believe I missed reading that part. Thank you!